# Painting Foundation - Regular Paint or Elastomeric Paint?

Tags: painting, foundation, exterior, repainting, cement

I need to paint the cinder block foundation (Above grade) on a house I bought recently. The condition isn't great, not cracked, but it looks like it possibly had some thin stucco on it in parts. I want to get a coat of paint on the foundation to make it look nice, and the minimal chance of helping with any water.

The house gutters were a mess and most of the water was running right into the foundation, so water was pooling and I could see some water in the basement after the heaviest of rain. Now that I put new gutters all around I have not seen water since. However, I want to get a fresh coat of paint on the foundation, and put some type of sealant where the asphalt meets the block foundation.

Are the elastomeric paints ideal for above grade foundation so it looks better? I figured I'd consider this paint since it has some flex to it and may fill in any teeny tiny cracks it may have. This is above grade so no water in theory should be going through it anyhow.

Any paint prep and primer/paint tips appreciated.

Comment: Clean off any pealing or flaking , then spring for the elastomeric paint.